# Why am I getting a "get" request when it should be a "post" request

Tags: html, forms, post, get, request

I am trying to submit the form below to upload a file, however whenever I submit the form the request coming accross is a 'GET REQUEST'.  Is this just my browser being buggy?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmUploadDoc2" target="hiddenIframe" method=”POST” action="/rest/wle">
   <input id="myFileName" type="file" name="data" />
   <input type="text" name="action" value="addDocument" />
   <input type="text" name="accept" value="application/json" />
   <input type="text" name="parts" value="none" />
   <input type="text" name="name" value="myTestQ1" />
   <input type="text" name="docType" value="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<iframe name="hiddenIframe" id="hiddenIframe" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: Any chance you're submitting via AJAX?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Special character quotes might be the culprit:

```
method=”POST”
```

Those are `&rdquo;` generated quotes. Replace those with a simple keyboard `"` (double quote)

Comment: @JeffSilva - Probably just picked up from a quick copypasta -- happy coding!

Answer (score 6):

Your `method` argument is using wrong quotes:

```
method=”POST”
```

As a consequence the value of `method` is interpreted as an unquoted value and it’s not `POST`, it’s `”POST”`. The browser doesn’t know how to handle that value and silently replaces it by `GET`.